# How to mock 'replace' function with Jest Javascript React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, tdd

I use Jest as unit testing on the React Native App I created. For currency formatting purposes I use the 'replace' function from Javascript as below:

This my code :

```
amount.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,'$1.',)
```

I'm getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read property' replace 'of undefined' while running my TDD Jest

Please help, thank you

Comment: Can you show full block of code?

Comment: This my code ```        <Text style={styles.textCurrency}>
                Rp {amount.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.')}
              </Text> ```

Comment: You sure that 'amount' is always defined? You can do then: if (amount) { expect(amount.replace(...)).toEqual(...); }

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to mock that method, because: 1. It's a standard method on strings, not a collaborator that needs a test double; and 2. The problem is you *don't* have a string, amount is undefined.

Comment: Ok thanks Already Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already Solved, Because I Using Props.

Show The Solution is you make a default value first for handling that before the data already sent.